# Multiple digest run for the code below

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a infinite digest cycle error with the filter code below. What is incorrect with it. I do not see an issue with this. Is there a different method of assignation or is it a known bug? I am not sure whats happening here with this error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Directives</title>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test Text for style</h1>
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="var in variable | filtername:'test':'test2':'test3' track by $index">
       {{var}}
    </div>


</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("demo",[]);

app.filter("filtername",function(){

    return function(array, arrayField, arrayField1, arrayField2){        
        /* modification here */
        var myArr = [];

        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){

            if((array[i].name===arrayField) || (array[i].name===arrayField1) ||(array[i].name===arrayField2)){
                myArr.push({name: angular.uppercase(array[i].name)});
            }
        }
        return myArr;
    }
})

app.controller("firstCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.variable = [
        {name:"test"},
        {name:"test2"},
        {name:"test3"},
        {name:"test4"}]; 

})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seem like this issue caused by `myArr.push({name: angular.uppercase(array[i].name)});`, if simply use `myArr.push(array[i])`, iteration stack error disappeared

Comment: yes. when I am using `array[i].name.toUpperCase();` even then it is triggering a `more than 10 digest cycle` error.